# Replace and restore the object in `globalenv()` during a function call

Tags: r

I need to call a function, named `g`, whose behavior depends on the variable under `globalenv()` several times. For convenience, I try to wrap it into a helper function, named `f`. However, I hope that after executing `f`, the `globalenv()` is invariant.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
g <- function(name) {
  print(globalenv()[[name]])
}

f <- function(w) {
  # backup "w" in globalenv if needed
  is_existed.w <- !is.null(globalenv()[["w"]])
  if (is_existed.w) {
    temp.w <- globalenv()[["w"]]
  }
  w <<- w
  g("w")
  # restore w if needed
  if (is_existed.w) {
    w <<- temp.w
  }
}

w <- "a"
f("gg")
w
```

However, this approach is very tedious. I need to copy-paste many times. Is there an more elegant way to implement this?

Comment: If your function's behaviour depends on X, then X really should be an argument to the function.

Comment: I agree. But the function `g` is in another package. Therefore I tend to not modify `g` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to copy and paste? If it is because you'd want to save different variables, or call different functions, you could pass both of these as arguments to a higher order function, i.e. a function returning a function, like this:

```
wrap <- function(name, g) {
  f <- function(value, ...) {
    old <- globalenv()[[name]]
    assign(name, value, globalenv())
    res <- g(...)
    if (!is.null(old))
      assign(name, old, globalenv())
    return (res)
  }
  return (f)
}
```

You could then create your `f` using `wrap("w", g)` and call it using `f("gg", "w")`, the latter `"w"` being the name of the variable you want to print.

Comment: Thanks. I forget to try the technique of closure.